# best geometry for kirigami in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to model simple pop-up kirigami objects in three.js.  Here are some real-world examples:

[image: simple paper popup 1]

[image: simple paper popup 2]

At the moment I can build them using Shape objects, first drawn in 2d and then rotated and translated into place.

It works, but I wonder if there's a more appropriate sort of geometry I should be using, to recreate the whole sheet of paper as a single object in three.js, instead of a collection of individual surfaces.  Ultimately  I'd like to be able to open and close the popup.

I've read and reread the docs and examples, but I can't figure this one out.  I'm new to threejs and dazzled by its capabilities, but it's a steep learning curve.  Thanks for any wisdom.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating this kind of shape from a single mesh. In that case, you would need to update the vertices of the geometry as you fold/unfold the object, which means you're constantly changing the buffer sent to the GPU. You say you've used `Shape`, which is fine if you want to programmatically define the outline of the shape. If you have static corners in mind, you could use `BufferGeometry` to define the shape, and use it to create a `Mesh` just like you do now. Long story short, you're doing it the right way with multiple meshes.

Comment: Thanks.  When I change the positions of the points in my current model, I have to go through and update the vertices in all the shapes anyway.  And it's a step or two trickier, in that they don't take `Vector3`'s, because `Shape` doesn't do that, so I must change the shapes'  `Vector2`'s and their `.rotation`'s, and then update those things.  I was hoping that, if there were a way I could construct a single complex mesh, I could keep everything in 3-space (so that my rendering matches my mathematical model), and do a single `updateVertices` on the whole.

Comment: OK, then you're still doing it the hard way. Consider any mesh. You can change its `position`/`rotation`, rather than updating its vertices. When you change the `position`/`rotation`, it affects the entire shape all at once. So as long as you can calculate where a shape should be at a certain fold angle (so the edges remain aligned), then you only need to update two values for each shape mesh, rather than updating all the vertices. Does that make sense? If I get some time later, I'll create a fiddle as an example.

Comment: Thanks, and I do understand.  My project is to create algorithmically-adjustable pop-ups.  So first it makes the Object3D containing all the meshed Shape objects, but then it needs to go in there and adjust all their vertices based on a series of algorithms controlled by the UI.  The shapes are not just changing position and rotation, but shape, as the user fiddles with the settings.  So I think I do need to calculate individual vertices, and then do updateVertices. My model computes the points as Vector3's, but the Shape objects take Vector2's, so that's why I was hoping for a single geom.